# Difference of closed convex cones

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, convex-cone

I have read the following claim

> The difference of two closed convex cones in $\mathbb R^n$ can be non closed

but I am not convinced and cannot manage to find a counter-example, can you find any?

By difference of sets $A,B$ I mean the algebraic difference:
$$A-B:=\{x\in \mathbb R^n: \exists a\in A,b\in B,\ \ x=a-b\}$$

Answer (score -1):

Choose in $\mathbb{R}^3$ two circular cones $C_1$ and $C_2$ with common zero apex, which touch each other along a halfline, say $h$. Denote by $H$ the plane separating $C_1$ and $C_2$. Then $C_1 - C_2$ is the convex set consisting of the open halfspace (bounded by $H$ and containing $C_1$ and $-C_2$) and the line $h \cup (-h)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).